# Error "Tabla esta mutando" en PL-SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, trigger

!Buenas!

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que dice así:

> Al insertar o modificar un cliente, hay que añadir dicho id al nombre.
>   De igual modo se registrará en el log.

Estas son las tablas que utilizo:

```
Clientes (id, nombre)
Vendedores (id, nombre)
Ventas (id_clienteFK, id_vendedorFK, importe, fecha)
Tabla_log(id,tipo,descripción)
```

Esta es la solución que he pensando:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertar_cliente AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON clientess
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    concadenado VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
    concadenado := concat(:old.id,:old.nombre);
    INSERT INTO tabla_log values (2,'insertar','Se ha adjuntado el ID al nombre');
    UPDATE clientess set nombre=concadenado WHERE :old.id = clientess.id;
END;
```

Pero me ha saltado este error cuando he probado el `Insert`:

> RUNTIME EXCEPTION ORA-04091: la tabla SYSTEM.CLIENTESS está mutando,
>   puede que el disparador/la funcion no puedan verla. Error durante la ejecucion del disparador 'SYSTEM.INSERTAR_CLIENTE'

Y la verdad no se si es problema de sintaxis en el `Trigger` o por que estoy utilizando mal el `:new` y `:old`.

Si pueden ayudarme lo agradecería. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El usuario @Valentín Sánchez Boto te pregunta **. Si supiese de donde sacas el Id o como es tu tabla y el Insert que usas podria intentar ayudar.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce porque dentro del trigger que fue activado al hacer una operación sobre la tabla `clientess`, estás queriendo modificar la misma tabla `clientess` con:

```
UPDATE clientess set nombre=concadenado WHERE :old.id = clientess.id;
```

Por otro lado en insert no hay `:old`, me parece que deberías trabajar con `:new` solamente para hacer lo que te han pedido.

Comment: De acuerdo con esta respuesta. El trigger sobre una tabla no debe modificar la misma tabla. Y sí, para triggers de insert o update, es mala idea usar `:old` porque en los inserts `:old` es nulo (aunque esta no es la causa del error mostrado).

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan. La verdad que aun no controlo bien todo este tema. Efectivamente uno de los problemas era que debía poner el `:new`. Luego he tenido que ajustar una otra pero gracias a esto lo resolví bien.

Answer (score 0):

CREO QUE DE FORMA SEPARADA, SI ESTOY ENTENDIENDO LO QUE QUIERES HACER, SE HARIA MEJOR, DE TODAS MANERAS NO DEJAS MUY CLARO QUE ES LO QUE TE PIDEN HACER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insertar_cliente AFTER INSERT ON Clientes
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tabla_log values (:new.id,'insertar','Se ha adjuntado el ID al nombre');
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER actualizar_cliente AFTER UPDATE ON Clientes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tabla_log values (:new.id, 'actualizar','....');
END;
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], la zona de respuestas no es el espacio adecuado para hacer preguntas al OP de su pregunta

Comment: Y como le hago una pregunta para intentar responer si no puedo comentar?

Comment: tendrás que esperar a tener 50 puntos de reputación, los cuales seguro ganas rápido, de todos modos se gustas le puedo dejar tu pregunta al OP en la zona de comentarios

Comment: Adelante, porque si no es de esta manera no puedo hacerle una pregunta para intentar ayudarle con una respuesta

Comment: hecho, en cuanto veas que el OP modifica su pregunta tu haz lo mismo

Comment: Editado. Ya tienes las tablas colocadas. Gracias